# Android db.update where string

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using the method db.update to update the data according to the id.

now I would like at the same time change the same data that is present in another table. but the second part of the code does not work .... you have any ideas?

```
    cv.put(CategorieTable.NOME_CATEGORIA, Ecatgoria.getText().toString());
            String idc = id.getText().toString();
            SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.update(CategorieTable.TABLE_NAME, cv, idc + "=" + CategorieTable._ID, null);

            //THE SECOND PART

            cv.put(GiornateTable.CATEGORIA, Ecatgoria.getText().toString());
            String nCategoria = Ecatgoria.getText().toString();
            db.update(GiornateTable.TABLE_NAME, cv, nCategoria + "=" + GiornateTable.CATEGORIA, null);
```

Comment: What does not work? Stacktrace, description of what you expect and what the program does, ...

Comment: You are using the same ContentValues instance (cv) for both operations. At second part try to call `cv.clear()`, before put the new values.

Comment: this is the error, seems that the second part goes to look for the field in the first part of the code
 
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: nome_categoria (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE Giornate SET categoria=?,nome_categoria=? WHERE wa=categoria

Comment: Ok, Then I will post the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same ContentValues instance (cv) for both operations. At second part you need to call cv.clear(), before put the new values.

```
        cv.put(CategorieTable.NOME_CATEGORIA, Ecatgoria.getText().toString());
        String idc = id.getText().toString();
        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.update(CategorieTable.TABLE_NAME, cv, idc + "=" + CategorieTable._ID, null);

        //THE SECOND PART

        cv.clear(); // Clean the Content Values.
        cv.put(GiornateTable.CATEGORIA, Ecatgoria.getText().toString());
        String nCategoria = Ecatgoria.getText().toString();
        db.update(GiornateTable.TABLE_NAME, cv, nCategoria + "=" + GiornateTable.CATEGORIA, null);
```

Comment: I believe that the second query is wrong, I do the update based on the string and not by id